# Disabling caching for a Drupal 8 block

Tags: php, symfony, drupal-8

When a return a render array for a block and specify the following:

```
'#cache' => [ 'max-age' => 0 ]
```

Drupal **STILL** caches the block!

How do I properly disable it?

Answer (score 4):

Override the `getCacheMaxAge` of your block's class with the value `0`.

```
class MyBlock extends BlockBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build() {
        // Returns the block content as a render array
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getCacheMaxAge() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As implied [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-max-age) in the Drupal 8 documentation, you must invalidate the tags associated with the block.

How I ended up "disabling" caching for a specific block was to use an event subscriber to invalidate the tags for said block.

**Event Subscriber:**

```
class MyBlockCacheInvalidator implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    protected $cacheTagsInvalidator;
    public function __construct(CacheTagsInvalidatorInterface $cache_tags_invalidator) {
        $this->cacheTagsInvalidator = $cache_tags_invalidator;
    }
    public function onRequest(KernelEvent $event) {
        $this->cacheTagsInvalidator->invalidateTags(['my_block_tag']);
    }
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        $events = [];
        $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('onRequest');
        return $events;
    }
}
```

**Service Entry:**

```
services:            
    my_block.cache_invalidator:
        class: Drupal\my_module\EventSubscriber\MyBlockCacheInvalidator
        arguments: ['@cache_tags.invalidator']
        tags:
            - { name: event_subscriber }
```

**Block Build Response:**

```
return [
    '#theme' => 'my_block_theme',
    '#var1' => $some_value,
    '#cache' => [
        'max-age' => 0,
        'tags' => ['my_block_tag']
    ],
];
```

This solution worked for me, but it isn't efficient.